# RequireJS Knockout Amd-Helper

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, knockout-amd-helpers

I'm struggling with arranging my code using requireJS and will appreciate any help.

I have a dashboard.html which gets bound to the 'dashboard' viewmodel in dashboard-init.js. The dashboard viewmodel has a list of Panels that get shown as a list in dashboard.html.

After the render completes, I invoke the gridList function to convert the list into a dashboard.

Please note that this works correctly if I simply include these scripts in the html using script src=... etc.

But when I removed the script tags and pushed these dependencies to dashboard viewmodel, I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return { data:Panels,afterRender:postRender} }" Message: GridList lib required
```

What do I need to do to satisfy the GridList lib requirement?

Here is the page that is giving this error (dashboard.html):

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <ul id="grid" class="grid" data-bind="foreach: { data: Panels, afterRender: postRender }">
            <li ...">
                ...
            </li>            
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="Scripts/require.js"></script>
    <script src="viewmodels/common-init.js"></script>
    <script src="viewmodels/dashboard-init.js"></script>

</body>
```

This is what common-init looks like:

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: "../Scripts",
paths: {
    "jquery": "jquery-2.0.3.min",
    "jqueryui": "jquery-ui-1.11.4.min",
    "knockout": "knockout-3.3.0",
    "knockout-amd-helpers": "knockout-amd-helpers",
    "text": "text"
},
shim: {
    'gridList': ['jquery'],
    'jquery.gridList': ['jquery','gridList']
}
```

});

Here is dashboard-init

```
require(["knockout", "../viewmodels/modules/dashboard", "knockout-amd-helpers", "text"], function (ko, dashboard) {

ko.amdTemplateEngine.defaultPath = "../templates";

ko.bindingHandlers.module.baseDir = "modules";

ko.bindingHandlers.module.templateProperty = "embeddedTemplate";

setTimeout(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new dashboard());
}, 0);
```

});

Finally, here is the dashboard module:

```
define(["knockout", "jquery", "jqueryui", "gridList", "jquery.gridList"], function (ko) {
return function () {
    var self = this;

    self.Panels = [{...}, {...}];

    self.postRender = function(elements, data) {
        if (this.foreach[this.foreach.length - 1] === data) {
            $('#grid').gridList({
                rows: 3,
                widthHeightRatio: 264 / 294,
                heightToFontSizeRatio: 0.25
            });
        }
    }
};
```

});

Also, I don't like the fact that I need to refer to #grid inside the viewmodel but do not know any better. Any advice would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the `gridList` that you are working with, but I see that they have  a check for `window.GridList` that is throwing the error that you are seeing. In an AMD setting, it is not exposed on the window. They should check that the GridList from their dependency is there instead.

You can work around this by doing:

```
define(["knockout", "jquery", "gridList", "jqueryui", "jquery.gridList"], function (ko, $, GridList) {
        window.GridList = GridList;

        // your other code
    });
```

As far as accessing the `#grid` element, you could access any of the elements `parentNode` instead or better consider using a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) on the parent element that actually initializes the `GridList`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked with one slight change: moved the function arguments to the outer function signature.  As for the  custom binding, I'd love to see an example in action if you can point to it. I did try to go through the reference but not sure how to implement. Thanks once again.